# Drawing bezier curve with limited subdivisions in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to tell OpenGL to draw a 4 degree (5 control points) bezier curve with 10 subdivisions?

I was trying with this:

```
point ctrlpts[] = {..., ..., ..., ...};
glMap1f(GL_MAP1_VERTEX_3, 0, 1, 3, 5, ctrlpts);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
      for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) 
         glEvalCoord1f((GLfloat) i/30.0);
glEnd();
```

But this just draws the curve nicely. I am thinking that I want the algorithm inside the bezier curve to draw only until 10 subdivisions and then stop. The line should look a little facet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just loop from 0 to 10 and divide by 10.

OpenGL only knows planar primitives. Curves lie beyond it's grasp. What evaluators do is, they allow you to tell OpenGL coefficients of interpolating function, then you tell OpenGL to sample the function for the parameters given.

Technically OpenGL evaluators are outdated technology. Neither are they HW accelerated, nor do the make driver development simpler. They got removed from OpenGL-3 core, for the simple reason, that you can implement evaluator like functionality using a vertex shader, which is then accelerated by the GPU, and you can put tesselators on them to generate the sampling points on the GPU as well.

Comment: By dividing from 0 to 10, is that really subdivision into 10 parts or is it merely "look like" 10 subdivisions? Just curious, is it possible to get the coordinates itself from `glEvalCoord1f()`?

Comment: @xEnOn: It is really 10 subdivisions. glEvalCoord1f acts like a wrapper that evaluates the bezier curve for the given parameter and calls glVertex for it. OpenGL itself is just a drawing API not a math or geometry library, so trying to "get" values from glEvalCord1f is misguided (though not impossible if some hoops are jumped). Just evaluate the Bezier curve yourself. You have the control points, and Wikipedia the formula/algorithm. If you fed the output to glVertex calls, the result would be indistinguishable.